# ApexCharts.js RTL Support

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, apexcharts

I am using the apexcharts.js library and my app supports Arabic language, when the RTL mode is activated the tooltip appears as follow. Notice how the tooltip takes full width.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know this is too late . Please try to set a boolean variable that takes if isRTL or not, then set **opposite** attribute, in **chartOptions>yaxix**, to isRTL value and reverse series data like the code below.

```js
let isRTL = true
```

```js
let chartOptions: {
  //... your options
  yaxix:{
    //... your yaxix options
    opposite: this.isRTL
  }
}
```

```js
let series = [...]
if(this.isRTL){
  series.map(s => s['data'].reverese())
}
```

I hope this solution will work for you.
Good luck .

Answer (score 2):

you can add style to it like this:

```
    type: 'area',
    height: 100,
    style:{
        direction: 'rtl'
    },
    ......
```